# Entity framework: Group creator null but it's not?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Here's my code grabbing the group creator name:

```
Group grp = uow.GroupRepository.Get(u => u.GroupId == groupId).First();
string creator = grp.creator.UserName.ToString();
```

Group class:

```
public class Group
    {
        public int GroupId { get; set; }
        public Group() { this.Members = new HashSet<ApplicationUser>(); this.LockedUsers = new HashSet<string>(); this.active = true; this.Locked = true; this.LockedUntil = DateTime.Now; }
        public virtual string GroupName { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser creator { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Members { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<string> LockedUsers { get; set; }
        public bool active { get; set; }
        public bool Locked { get; set; }
        public DateTime LockedUntil { get; set; }
    }
```

Ok, so when an event gets to that first line, it uses the unit of work object to get the group. This works fine in debug, when getting ANY other variable (e.g.

```
string groupname = grp.GroupName();
```

)

So, here's the wierd part. I run the code, I get a NULL exception and visual studio sits there giving me some cheeky excuse. I open up the database, look at all the group data and everything is there. Then I hover over the group object and suddenly it's registering a group creator.... no longer says it's null. I have no idea why this won't work.

Comment: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}
An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ***.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: Which makes no sense because when I look in the test DB it does have a value and after a couple mins I hover back over the creator string and now it's assigned correctly

Comment: What exactly is null? Are you saying that you get a NRE, and the debugger tells you that `foo` is null, and you come back after a moment and find that the debugger is telling you that `foo` is no longer null? While still paused in the debugger?

Comment: Just for sake of curiosity, try to get rid of the virtual keyword and see if that helps you. I have a feeling it's got to do with lazy loading. Check on that.

Comment: michael - that exactly

Comment: there is no virtual on creator mate

Comment: `string groupname = grp.GroupName();` is obviously not part of your real code and won't work. As for the suggestion to remove `virtual` -- you should consistently get a `NullReferenceException` if you remove the `virtual` from the other properties. One of those other properties getting lazily loaded (as a result of the debugger evaluating properties) is also causing `creator` to get set.

Comment: grp is an instance of the Group class and does work. It was just a segmented part as an example.
Creator is supposed to be set, that's the point.
Adding virtual to the creator actually fixed it.
Many thanks for all your answers guys: Since @ilanS gave me the right inkling I will accept your answer if you post. 

Many thanks to all for your inputs

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the answer is "add virtual in-front of the creator". If you read this and understand WHY please edit this and I'll update. Many thanks to @ilanS

Comment: Yes, that's lazy loading for you. Lazy loading is enabled only for `virtual` properties. If you make some properties `virtual`, and others not, then only some of those properties can have lazy loading enabled. And evaluation of another property may cause an object to get loaded. If that object happens to be the same object as referenced by a non-lazy-loading property, the non-lazy-loading property will still get set.

Comment: that makes sense, so if you add it to any in a model, you need to add it to all?

Comment: Why do they not do this on asp.net examples though e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542

Comment: Basically, yes, having lazy loading enabled for some properties and disabled for others is likely to cause confusing results. Having it enabled for all properties, or having it disabled for all properties, both of those can make sense and can have their advantages (for example: if your application disposes of the context before it is done with the retrieved objects, you don't want lazy loading to silently attempt to continue using the context). I suspect that the examples you were looking at didn't use lazy loading at all.

Comment: Oh, sorry, let me clarify: lazy loading only applies to navigation properties. For lazy loading to work, primitive properties may still be non-virtual. While making primitive properties virtual would allow change tracking, that's completely separate from lazy loading. The example you link to does consistently use `virtual` for navigation properties, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: sorry it was string creator = grp.creator.UserName.ToString(); which was breaking, and creator didnt have virtual infront.
But thanks for clearing this up: Now i know WHY it won't happen again. :)